# Html forms and mobile web browsers problem

Tags: iphone, android, mobile-website

Mobile keyboard (Android IPhone) has no tab button. That is why native application go to next field when enter is pressed. However browser forms are submitted when enter is pressed.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`tabindex`](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/interact/forms.html#adef-tabindex) properly and it should work just like with native applications.

By the way, on Android at least, native apps don't have to do anything special to get this behavior (at most they have to specify `nextFocusForward`, if the layout is too complicated and Android can't figure that out by itself).

Comment: Have you tested this? It doesn't work on my Android 2.3. Currently Im using tabindex to focus next field using jquery. However keyboard doesn't appear after next field is focused.

Comment: Yes, here's what it looks like on the 2.3 emulator: http://i.imgur.com/R9l9z.png -- I didn't even use `tabindex`. Pressing the highlighted button while the username input is focused moves the focus to the password input.

Comment: On my phone it inserts tab inside input

Comment: Samsung S5380 with Android 2.3.3

Comment: I can see it comes with Swype, so maybe that's the problem. Try long-clicking on an `EditText` -> select **Input Method** -> **Android keyboard**

Answer (score 2):

I assume you're talking about the on-screen keyboard. iPhone will show  `Previous | Next` as a keyboard accessory in web forms. Android will too.

If they don't then something might be wrong with your markup. Is it possible for you to post your form HTML code?

I would also say that nLL's suggestion is correct. It will make it feel more polished.

Comment: I've got no next previous buttons on Android. Have tried on http://twitter.com/#!/login

Comment: @Alexey it's a problem with your device / virtual keyboard. For example, Swype doesn't seem to work on Twitter's login page, while the default Android keyboard does.

Answer (score -2):

since you are targeting high-end phones you can handle enter key with simple JavaScript

```
var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
if(code == 13) { //Enter keycode
 //Do something
}
```

Comment: There's no need to use JavaScript for this.

Comment: Doesn't he want to handle enter key? doesn't tabindex only display arrow on the keyboard?

Comment: He didn't specify he wants to handle the enter key. He just wants something tab-like from the desktop (from what I understand).

Comment: As far as I understand he asks how to go to next input when user preses to enter OR prevent submitting the form and move to next empty input